# SSH to personal VPS through company's network that's behind firewall

Tags: ssh, proxy

I've seen a lot of question mostly trying to access server that's behind firewall, but I'm trying to find the other way around where my personal server is not, but I'm at work and trying to access it on a network that's behind firewall.

In my `~/.ssh/config` I currently have this

```
Host *
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host hostname
    HostName xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
    User username
    Port 2345
```

and when I ssh to it it will just stuck on here:

```
➜  ~ ssh hostname -v
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/alialdallal/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/alialdallal/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/alialdallal/.ssh/config line 6: Applying options for hostname
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx] port 2345.
```

In my `fish` env I have these proxy set

```
all_proxy=http://hostname:8000
ftp_proxy=http://hostname:8000
http_proxy=http://hostname:8000/
https_proxy=http://hostname:8000/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://hostname:8000
HTTP_PROXY=http://hostname:8000
FTP_PROXY=http://hostname:8000
ALL_PROXY=http://hostname:8000
```

What option do I need to pass or what do I need to change on my personal VPS to allow this connection through?

Comment: Is your goal here to intentionally bypass your work's network security/filtering by proxying through your VPS?

Comment: I just want to avoid having to switch to my LTE to ssh to my box and switch back to my work's network every time I want to ssh to my VPS is really all I want to accomplish here.

Comment: If that's the case, why not ask your work's network admin to allow you to ssh to your VPS?

Comment: @jscott If this is a work network configuration needed to allow this connection through then it will be easier for me to continue with LTE option to be honest. I just thought there maybe an option where I can bridge or tunnel it through to get to my VPS without having to disconnect and connect to another network here.

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is that it's not a matter of the configuration of your machine but of your workplace firewall, the only solution would be to talk to the sysadmin to open up a rule for you.